# 2 arrays in a foreach

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I need your help :( , I've been trying to find a solution to this problem for hours.

I have 2 arrays, the `$result_users_auris_in_turn` array has 3 records and the `$result` array has 38 records, what I need is to create a `foreach` that records the 38 records of the `$result` array in the `$result_users_auris_in_turn` array has,

I have tried many ways but it doesn't work, this is my code:

The result if I execute that code is this:

```
$items = array();
          foreach( $resultado as $index => $code ) {  
            if (isset($resultado_users_auris_en_turno[$index])) {
                $varios = 
                $varios = ($resultado_users_auris_en_turno[$index].'.'.$code);
                $items[]  = $varios;
            }else{
            }
         }
```

The result if I execute that code is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => KNEIRAG.105272637
    [1] => TGOMEZA.105272638
    [2] => JPACHECOM.105272800
)
```

but the array of 38 records is cut at position 3 of the other array. I need it to be like this:

```
KNEIRAG  -  105272637
TGOMEZA  -  105272638
JPACHECOM  -  105272800
KNEIRAG  -  105269374
TGOMEZA  -  105269375
JPACHECOM  -  105269378
KNEIRAG  -  105269379
TGOMEZA  -  105269380
JPACHECOM  -  105269876
KNEIRAG  -  105269877
TGOMEZA  -  105269879
JPACHECOM  -  105270217
KNEIRAG  -  105270260
TGOMEZA  -  105270576
JPACHECOM  -  105270577
KNEIRAG  -  105270580
TGOMEZA  -  105270581
JPACHECOM  -  105270582
KNEIRAG  -  105270584
TGOMEZA  -  105270588
JPACHECOM  -  105270590
KNEIRAG  -  105270592
TGOMEZA  -  105272056
JPACHECOM  -  105272057
KNEIRAG  -  105272058
TGOMEZA  -  105272059
JPACHECOM  -  105272060
KNEIRAG  -  105272061
TGOMEZA  -  105272062
JPACHECOM  -  105272063
KNEIRAG  -  105272064
TGOMEZA  -  105272065
JPACHECOM 105272066
KNEIRAG  -  - 105272067
TGOMEZA  -  105272068
JPACHECOM  -  105272069
KNEIRAG  -  105272070
```

Do you know of a way to do this?

I expected to be able to allocate the 38 records of the array `$resultado_users_auris_en_turno`

Comment: Your question is not clear, please explain better. It would be great if you provide the inputs and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the mentioned variables are shaped like:

```php
$resultado_users_auris_en_turno = [
  'KNEIRAG',
  'TGOMEZA',
  'JPACHECOM',
];

$resultado = [
  '105272637',
  '105272638'
  // …
];
```

Then you can do the following:

```php
$items = array();
foreach ($resultado as $index => $code) {
  $items[] = $resultado_users_auris_en_turno[$index % 3] . '.' . $code;
}
```

The trick is the `$index % 3`:

| `$index` value | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 0 |

As you can see, it loops through `0`, `1` and `2` so you always get a value from `$resultado_users_auris_en_turno`.

Comment: this is just what you need!!

query: if the results of $auris_users_result_in_turn change to 5 records, do I have to manually change the number 3 from [$index % 3] or is there a way to count the records automatically?

thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: You can indeed make it dynamic. Instead of having a hard-coded number, you can use the [`count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function like `$index % count($resultado_users_auris_en_turno)`.